# Convert bundle from BundleConfig.cs to gulp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gulp, bundle

I have the following bundle in my `RegisterBundles()` method of the `BundleConfig.cs` file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
    "~/Scripts/jquery.serializeObject.js",
    // https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mathiasbynens/he/master/he.js
    "~/Scripts/he.js"));
```

They all have minified versions (`.min.js`) in the `Scripts` folder, so no minification needs to occur. As they are vendor libraries, no transpiling is required either. They just need to be added as one bundle, using their existing minified versions.

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208017/jquery-library-not-working-after-gulp-bundle) to help me. Here's what I've got thus far:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src
        ([
        "Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js",  // --> what glob do you use for {version}?
        "Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
        "Scripts/jquery.serializeObject.min.js",
        "Scripts/he.min.js"
        ])
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'));
});
```

Notice the line with `{version}`. Using `BundleConfig.cs`, it's currently grabbing jquery-3.2.1.min.js, and any future ones I put there. Is there an equivalent way in gulp to do this using a glob pattern?

Also, is the above the correct way to bundle vendor libraries in gulp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `*` (star) character.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            "Scripts/jquery-*.min.js", // --> what glob do you use for {version}?
            "Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
            "Scripts/jquery.serializeObject.min.js",
            "Scripts/he.min.js"
        ])
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js/'));
});
```

Then it will use all your jQuery files no matter which version they have.